# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'statViewServlet'

Tags: java, spring, druid

The exception is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'statViewServlet' defined in class path resource [com/schoolpackage/schooltransaction/config/DruidConfig.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4629104a]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at com.schoolpackage.schooltransaction.SchoolTransactionApplication.main(SchoolTransactionApplication.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4629104a]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:758)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:690)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:410)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:394)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:332)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/servlet/MultipartConfigElement;
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3014)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2207)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:753)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

I am using Spring5's Webflux to create reactive web framework and using com.alibaba.druid as the dataSource. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>10</java.version>
    <mybatis.version>1.3.2</mybatis.version>
    <pageHelper.version>1.2.5</pageHelper.version>
    <json-lib-ext-spring.version>1.0.2</json-lib-ext-spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib-ext-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${json-lib-ext-spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- 使用slf4j注解 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring boot集成mybatis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${mybatis.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.pagehelper</groupId>
        <artifactId>pagehelper-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${pageHelper.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- mybatis end-->

    <!-- spring boot集成redis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I set the StatViewServlet and WebStatFilter for druid's dataSource, I got the above exception, Here is my config file:

```
package com.schoolpackage.schooltransaction.config;

import com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource;
import com.alibaba.druid.support.http.StatViewServlet;
import com.alibaba.druid.support.http.WebStatFilter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class DruidConfig {
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        log.debug("Druid: 开始注入数据源.");
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(DruidDataSource.class).build();
    }
    //Exception starts here
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<StatViewServlet> statViewServlet(){
        log.info("Druid: 配置监控统计的登录信息.");
        ServletRegistrationBean<StatViewServlet> servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(
                new StatViewServlet(),"/druid/*");
        //监控白名单.
        servletRegistrationBean.addInitParameter("allow","127.0.0.1");
        servletRegistrationBean.addInitParameter("loginUsername","admin");
        servletRegistrationBean.addInitParameter("loginPassword","chenxiao123");
        servletRegistrationBean.addInitParameter("resetEnable","false");
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean statFilter(){
        log.info("Druid: 配置监控统计的过滤信息.");
        FilterRegistrationBean<WebStatFilter> filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new WebStatFilter());
        //添加过滤规则
        filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        filterRegistrationBean.addInitParameter("exclusions","*.js,*.jpg,*.png,*.jsp,/druid/*");
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

I am totally confused, please help me, thank you very much! :)

Comment: root cause of your exception is `ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement`. try to add dependency:

`<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`

Comment: thank you so much! My problem is solved! :)